# Show Two Divs with ID Link CSS without JS - Overlay and Content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use css to display a div with a href link.  My following markup that I have so far is simple:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row1">
        <a href="#content"><div id="box1"></div></a>

        <div id="box2"></div>
    </div>
```

When you click on the "box1" (which is a link with a background image) I want it to display a div with the "content" id.  The "content" div is inside another div with an id="overlay".

I would like to click on the link and display both the overlay div and the content div.  I do not want to use javascript.  I can use :target and display one div just fine, e.g. the "content" div or the "overlay" div.

The markup for the "overlay" and "content" divs:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <a href="#close">
        <div class="content">
            <strong class="closebutton" title="Close Content">X</strong>
                <h1>Awesome DIV Layer Technique</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>Content Goes Here</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

My relative at the moment CSS:

```
#content{
display: none;
width: 460px;
padding: 20px;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
cursor: auto;
position: relative;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.9;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, 
sans-serif;
}

#overlay:target{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

#close #overlay:target{
display: none;
}
```

I have tried to tweak my css everyway I can think of, by using class selectors, and combining them, but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to pull this off. I know I could use a '#overlay div{' but I am going to use this with multiple links and content divs so I need to be able to specify the divs from each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JsFiddle to create an example and post it here, someone may be more willing to take a stab at it.

Comment: Here is an example with a text link: http://jsfiddle.net/charlwillia6/8C4WC/ This example displays the overlay with the content that is inside the div with the id="overlay". What I want is to keep the overlay div as a container and then have the link actually point to the id="content" div, but at the same time still target the overlay and the content div. The reason I need this is so that I can have different "content" but keep using the "overlay" div multiple times.

Comment: I noticed that if I changed my .close class to an id selector and then used it in a link, such as href="#close", that in IE10 it gets hung with the faded overlay and no box in the center. It seems to have to do with the #close in the address. You can see it happen in this example: link You may have to click on the links several times in randomly to see it happen, but it does get stuck. Not sure why it does this, but that is why my solution avoids putting the #close in the href link. However my solution also reloads the page. Anyone know how to accomplish this without a page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with the [Futurebox](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/futurebox3) technique.  I had to totally reconstruct the css to meet my needs, but this seems to work in every browser just fine.  The [lightbox](http://www.htmlstack.com/lighterbox/) way is worthless in IE10 by the way.  If anyone really wants to see a solution to this, then message me. But actually this really had more to do with the placement of my divs in the markup than it did the styles.  Got to remember that they don't call them 'cascading' stylesheets for nothing. Had to write a few good classes to get it all to view correctly, but thats it.